# Comment Overflow?

Tags: bug, comments, google-chrome

I was reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins/227366#227366) when I saw a bug with [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins/227366#comment745417_227364):

[image]

It is quite evident that the user who commented this included some code in his comment, but the comment just, well, overflowed.

[image]

I am using Chrome 88 with Windows 10 (laptop).

The Chrome 88 version for Windows is supported. See: *[What browser version is supported?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/369403)*

> Credit: @ErikA

Comment: It doesn't overflow for me. Which browser are you using? Is it [supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/369403)?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+inline+code+overflows+in+comments) of [Large amounts of white-space in code cause comments to overflow in Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227187/289905).

Comment: @ErikA It overflows in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @SebastianSimon funny that the dupe is for firefox. Can we now conclude Chrome and Firefox are finally behaving the same, even for the rendering bugs? ;)  I can confrm the problem exists in Chrome / Win10.

Comment: Renders fine for me on FF on Mac

Comment: @ErikA, I am using Chrome88. Will update question shortly.

Comment: @rene, same here.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of this post on MSO: [Comment code format overflow covered by job](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403230/4642212). It’s a regression of [Code in comment overflows](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269890/4642212).

Comment: Related: [Inline code with lot of spaces overflow on the right side](/q/347630/289905).

Comment: Related: [Display bug on code block in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377855/display-bug-on-code-block-in-comments)

Comment: @justhalf not really "related". It's exactly the same bug. Nothing wrong, just saying. :-)

Comment: Yep, I'm just putting it there for additional duplicates that is targetting this. Hehe

Comment: @justhalf they're already listed, see in the right sidebar under "Linked". :-)

Comment: Is it listed there before I put the link here or after? I know that if I put a link to another question it will show up there. But not sure what other conditions it may appear (in this case the relevant one would be when the other question links here)

Comment: @justhalf yes the Linked Questions will always have the questions closed as duplicate of the current one. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376694/stack-exchange-changes-broke-ui-on-multiple-legacy-browsers-again) for example, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377838/show-n-more-comments-js-jquery?noredirect=1&lq=1) that appears under "Linked Questions" isn't mentioned in any comment or answer, just closed as duplicate.