# Display bug on code block in comments

Tags: bug, comments, design, code-formatting

I noticed this display bug on a [comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/what-is-the-number-of-the-parking-spot?rq=1#comment75927_1801), where the spaces inside code block is extended well past the comment width, and well beyond the content width as well, bleeding into the margins.

[image: Display bug]