# Code formatting sometimes overflows to the right column

Tags: bug, markdown, code-block

Here is an example in this now-deleted [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396923/178179):

[image: screenshot of metaSE post with pre-formatted text]

Copy-pasting the problematic line here:

`SELECT enterpriseid, lastUpdated, oldrecords,case when array_size(newrecords)>0 then                          explode_outer(newrecords) end as newrecord FROM  df_v`

Tested on Chrome 121.0.6167.185 (Official Build) (64-bit) + Windows 10 Pro 21H2 (19044.2006).

Comment: I'm able to reproduce as well.

Comment: On Edge, when I use the Caret Browsing feature and reach the end of the line, pressing right causes the cursor to stay still and not go into the overflowed space.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361250/comment-overflow except its about comments and not actual posts.... `Yes          This still happens                                                     even    years later!`