# Bounty cannot be awarded on a locked answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties, locked-answers

I wanted to award a bounty of 50 rep to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/298479) because it's great. However, while I could start the bounty I was not able to award it since that answer is locked.

It would be great if a moderator could either award the bounty to that answer manually (if that's possible) or unlock it for a few moments to allow me to award it.

On a side-note, "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be **voted on**." does not completely fit in this case.

Comment: Don't you think bobince has earned enough reputation for that answer?

Comment: He got zero since it's CW.

Comment: It was only made CW after almost a week, I'm sure he earned a few hundred rep in that time from it. (roughly 1000, from looking at his profile)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=31 - quite a few points

Comment: Actually it's _not_ a great answer. It's absolutely hilarious, a work of art, and historically significant, but as far as answers go, it's a typical "don't do that, try this instead" answer, a good answer to the question asked. [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/145633/25936), in contrast, is a great answer.

Comment: @Mat: `969`, to be exact. Not enough if we judge poetic beauty, but more than enough if we judge helpfulness.

Comment: Not that bloody post again :)

Comment: If you really want to award the bounty to someone, give it to [the guy that explained the problem based on Chomsky hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/616736)

Comment: I think it sucks that you can't award a bounty on an answer that is locked when the question itself *isn't* locked and still allows bounties. There's no notification to users that this would occur until after they've already placed the bounty on the question and attempted to award it. Whether this specific case warrants a bounty or not, **this is a real issue**.

Comment: @Dennis, where did you get that 969? I [count 967](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136235/how-can-i-view-all-the-reputation-gained-lost-for-one-specific-question/136337#136337).

Comment: @Arjan: I used jQuery on [his profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=32): After expanding the days (`$('.load-body').click()`), `var rep=0;$('.rep-breakdown-row').each(function(){if(~$(this).find('.answer-hyperlink').html().indexOf('RegEx match'))rep+=Number($(this).find('.rep-up').html())+Number($(this).find('.rep-down').html())});console.log(rep)` gives `969`. It is really great and does all things. (I don't know why, but pasting it here breaks my jQuery.)

Comment: Nice, @Dennis! To allow for line wrapping code in comments, SE [is inserting zero width spaces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow/42662#42662) every 80 characters (this [used to be soft hyphens](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page/2403#2403), making the JavaScript fail after copying. In your code: between the `n` and `k` in `answer-hyperlink`, and between the `o` and `w` in `.rep-down`. Removing that makes it work just fine. `969` it is indeed. Odd.

Comment: For copy & paste: *var rep=0;$('.rep-breakdown-row').each(function(){if(~$(this).find('.answer-hyperlin‌​k').html().indexOf('RegEx match'))rep+=Number($(this).find('.rep-up').html())+Number($(this).find('.rep-do‌​wn').html())});console.log(rep)*

Comment: @Arjan: Rep glitch. bobince *seems to* have earned `202` rep from upvotes on November 15, '09. Something similar happened to me the other day (it was due to an undownvote), but the nightly recalc fixed it. The jQuery was wrong: He earned `967` rep from that answer.

Comment: Good catch, @Dennis. (Took me some time to validate that, but indeed: for 3 questions a total of 217, including 15 for an accept which is exempt from the daily cap. That's 202 on the reputation page, where 200 should be the max.)

Comment: So you have changed your mind @animuson?

Comment: @Luuklag At the time they posted the comment, they weren't an employee, just a normal user.

Comment: Good to know @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. But still their mind has changed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug.

Locked questions are...  locked, which means they can not be changed (or even voted on).

Comment: I think the bug is the fact that he was allowed to post the bounty in the first place. Seems like that slipped through the cracks.

Comment: @jmort253: The *question* itself isn't locked, only that one answer.

Answer (score -2):

It's a hilarious answer, for sure - but not a *great* answer.  Award a bounty to those answers that rise above and beyond what the OP was looking for, and would reasonably help others looking for the same material for years to come.

We'll always get a laugh out of Bobince's answer for years to come, but as far as helpfulness goes, there are some other answers in that question that are helpful to an extent.