# Synonymise [locked-questions], [locked-answers] and [locked] to [locked-posts]

Tags: feature-request, meta, synonym-request

#### Suggestion

On Meta SE, synonymise:

- [locked-questions](/questions/tagged/locked-questions) → [locked-posts](/questions/tagged/locked-posts)
- [locked-answers](/questions/tagged/locked-answers) → [locked-posts](/questions/tagged/locked-posts)
- [locked](/questions/tagged/locked) → [locked-posts](/questions/tagged/locked-posts)

#### Rationale

While technically there is a difference between locked answers and locked questions, the vast majority of posts relating to locked posts apply to both.
In fact, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133739/255554) is the only question I could find that is exclusive to locked answers and here a tag helps little with finding the question or similar.
While these tags could theoretically be disentangled, this does not seem to be worth the effort.
Also, it is difficult or impossible for askers to discern whether their question is exclusive to one type of locked posts and thus which of the existing tags is most appropriate.

Therefore, we practically have three distinct tags with a strong overlap.
This makes it more difficult for users to find questions on this topic and yields unnecessary confusion when tagging posts.

I suggest [locked-posts](/questions/tagged/locked-posts) as a target tag to avoid confusion with locked votes, which are a separate thing.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354527/255554) is about the analogous situation for deleted posts, however I do not think that the problems can be treated the same as there is much more difference between deleted questions and answer than between locked questions and answers.

Comment: Your title says "synonymise", but I think we want to *merge* all those into one tag.  Is that what you're asking for?  If so, you might want to say "merge", as synonyms are a separate thing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: *as synonyms are a separate thing* – synonymisation is the pre-stage of merging. For most applications, the two are indistinguishable, and the main difference is that merging is much more difficult to undo. If the tags were synonymised for some time and no issues came up, of course they should be merged.

Comment: Synonyms still leave the three separate piles of questions, though -- a synonym kicks in when somebody *adds* a tag, but it doesn't go back and rewrite existing tagging.  A mod could merge all of these into one tag, however, without having to pass through synonymization.

Comment: @Ollie: See my edit and also my comment on that answer.