# Why do we have [deleted-questions] and [deleted-answers] tags when we have [deleted-posts]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta

The [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/deleted-posts/info) about [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts) is:

> For questions about questions or answers that are deleted.

If this tag is for questions about both deleted answers *and* deleted questions, then why do we have individual tags for both ([deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions), [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers))?  Aren't they redundant if we have one tag for both topics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the benefits of having all three of these tags is that, per the [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) tag usage guidance:

> You can also use this tag along with [specific-question] and [meta] to ask why a specific question on Meta Stack Exchange was deleted.

The same goes for [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers), though its tag wiki does not reflect it at the moment. It's useful to have these here for meta-discussions about Meta. Because... Meta.

Additionally, certain bug reports pertain only to a particular post type. Take [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/deleted-answers-should-get-sorted-at-the-very-bottom-of-the-answer-list) for example. This feature request *only* applies to deleted answers, and has nothing to do with deleted questions.

These more specific tags also house quite a few questions. [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) has 1,013 and [deleted-answers](/questions/tagged/deleted-answers) has 774 (at the time of writing.)

The [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts) tag (which has a measly 165 questions) is used for questions that refer to both deleted questions and deleted answers, much like the [feature request you recently created](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354526/add-the-ability-to-unfollow-deleted-posts-from-followed-tab). If anything, *this* is the tag that's less useful (and the low amount of posts tagged with it is indicative of that.) However, I don't think we really need to remove/burninate any of these tags - they're useful enough as they are.

There are a [couple of outliers that use all three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-posts+deleted-questions+deleted-answers), some of which could be retagged... but maybe not the [FAQ question on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/622284), where having the additional tags improves visibility.

If we were to merge everything into [deleted-posts](/questions/tagged/deleted-posts), we would also be intentionally making things *less* specific. This merge would also merge, at the time of writing, [1,655 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-questions+or+deleted-answers) into one much smaller tag for no real gain. Additionally, this tag's [wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/deleted-posts/info) is a bit lackluster...

So... Eh. I don't really see the harm in having all three. It allows for specificity without going overboard.

Comment: *I don't really see the harm in having all three* – Well, you have the problem that people don’t use the tagging system as you envision and always use *deleted posts* if applicable. Thus, e.g., if you have a general problem with deleted posts that is not clearly specific to answers or questions, you have to search three tags instead of one to find existing reports or solutions. This may be the lesser evil in this case, but it’s not that there is no harm.