# Can users award existing bounties on questions that get historically locked? Do automatic awards still work?

Tags: support, bounties, locked-questions, historical-lock

(Please note: while the topic of the example question cited here is controversial, this question is *not* a place to express your thoughts about it. This is a simple support question asking about the system.)

A user had just started a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio). Less than an hour later, it was historically locked. (The bounty probably wasn't the cause of the lock; otherwise, the bounty would have likely been cleared at the same time.)

Can the bounty still be awarded by the user, or can it no longer be awarded? If not, will automatic awarding still work? (Automatic awarding is moot in this specific question's case, since no answers were posted after the bounty was started, but I want to know for the general case.)

Also, what happens for other types of locks? I imagine that it would work since they work differently, but I'd still like to know.

[Bounty cannot be awarded on a locked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133739/bounty-cannot-be-awarded-on-a-locked-answer) does not address my question as that's for the case where the question was unlocked and the *answer* was individually, on its own, locked; in this case, the question is locked instead. Also, that question doesn't address the case of automatic awarding, which is mentioned here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they cannot. Due to the state of the question, the answer is also considered frozen and locked. No votes can be recorded to it, including a bounty - which is considered a type of vote which would be blocked. Bottom line: if you can't cast an upvote or downvote on the post, you cannot cast a bounty award on the post either. They are tied to the same permissions check.

An automatic award *would* go through, because the system bypasses the UserCanVote check in that scenario and just processes the bounty close immediately.