# Long words in script tags do not break

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

Similar to the problem described in [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow), long words don't break when they are placed inside `<script>` tags in a post.

Script tags seem to get removed when rendering, so I think the resulting text just needs to be wrapped in `<p>` tags to solve this problem. Or if the word wrapping is intentional, there should be a scrollbar.

Example:

wwwwwwwwwhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

There is another issue that would be solved if the text was rendered inside a paragraph. There is no space after placing a paragraph after a script tag.

```
<script>foo</script>


bar
```

results in:

foo

bar

Comment: I the text is even longer, it will add a horizontal scrollbar to the whole page.

Comment: `<iframe>` tags also work.

Comment: Interestingly, it does not affect the suggested edits page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18487

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Nice find, the compare edit page has a css rule `td.post-text` with `word-wrap: break-word;` which would also work on the default view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word` was only set on `.post-text p` and `.post-text li` (and the corresponding `.wmd-preview`), but it needs to be on everything (except for code blocks). Fixed in the next build.