# A long MathJax equation in a comment will make all comments overflow

Tags: bug, mathjax

If you look at the comments under [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1084908/195791), you'll notice they are overflowing:

[image: comment-overflow]

I'm guessing that this is because of the long number in the MathJax equation in the last comment, because when I delete it using Chrome's developer tools, it goes back to the normal size. This is similar to [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow) except that it's with MathJax equations instead of normal long words.

Comment: MathJax will overflow if misused. The commentator didn't make use of it well, and well, they messed it up.

Comment: Also mentioned on [meta.MO](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2390).