# Comment content (without spaces) overruns the comment area. Is this still not fixable?

Tags: bug, comments, design

This was brought up all the way back in 2010: [Comment overrun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66908/comment-overrun#comment160462_66908)

It was closed as a dupe of a question that was actually about question and answer content, not about comments... but the answer from [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42662/284336) is that it's not possible to fix in comments because they're variable width:

> Near as I can tell, there is no way to get this to work on comments because they are variable width. That is, the actual comment size depends on whether or not the comment vote UI controls are present (fex, on your own comment, you don't have controls, if you're not logged in there are no controls, etc), and if the comment has say 100 upvotes that's wider still.

I believe SE's page style has gone through some updates since then but it seems that these comments still run outside the post area:

[image: Crazy comments]

Is it still impossible to give them a max width to keep them neatly held beneath the post rather than flowing out all over the place? Clearly **something** prevents them from simply running off the page (unless Wad put a space in that I can't "see").

If this is still unfixable, feel free to dupe it, just thought I'd ask.