# Title goes beyond the border

Tags: bug, design

Related to [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

This question's title destroys the layout of Stack Overflow as you can see in the image.

The post I mentioned above was posted in 2009 and still the issue is there, because there is no space between a long title

[BeanDefinitionStoreException: IncompatibleClassChangeError, ClassMetadataRead‌​‌​ingVisitor has interface springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976026/nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-factory-support-defaultlistablebean):

[image: Question]

> Update
>   To make sure it is not an issue with client side,

Adding Screenshot in *Incognito*
[image]
As you can see, there is no error in the console and no scripts/styles are blocked.

Since the person edited the title, Check [**the revision link**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42976026/revisions).

Browser Details `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36` on Windows 10 x64

Comment: What browser/OS and versions? I cannot repro on latest Chrome/Opera/Edge/Vivaldi/FireFox, Windows 10.

Comment: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ike Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36` win 10. I refreshed 3 times and still the same. In console, the `analytics.js is blocked` but I believe this is not an issue with that

Comment: I was on the same version as you, now updated to `Version 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit)` - cannot repro.

Comment: @Oded the person edited the title. So try visiting the revision here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42976026/revisions

Comment: The same view in incognito with all scripts and styles allowed. So I hope you got it.