# Bio with a long URL breaks formatting

Tags: bug, profile-page

First noticed this over on SO on someone else's profile; they had a long URL in the bio, which made the bio expand beyond its normal size. There's a live example on my profile, but [here's a pic for later use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySJFJ.png).

<sub>This is slightly related to [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5460/332043), but it only seems to be implemented for posts and not the profile bio.</sub>